# AWS sagemaker pipeline conditional step execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

There are two s3 paths: the input data which comes daily and the ground truth data, which comes monthly. We are building a batch inference sagemaker pipeline wherein there would be a model quality step down the line which needs to run only when the ground truth data is available. We want to keep that step as a part of the inference pipeline only. So to avoid running that step every time we would like to build a logic that the model quality step should not run if the ground truth data is not available in the s3 bucket.

Also, suppose we would like to run the model quality step as soon as the ground truth data is available. To do that we would have to trigger the inference pipeline but in that scenario, we would like to build a logic that if the input data for the inference pipeline is older (the data on which the pipeline has already run once) then the initial pipeline steps like preprocessing and inferencing should be skipped. Control should be passed on directly to the model quality step which will again check for the data availability and run accordingly.